# How to append new column to tuple for each in the group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the following dataset in my postgres database:

```
 paperid | authorid |         name         |  
---------+----------+----------------------+
  896452 |     4976 | S. R. Duc            | 
  896452 |   186921 | F. Kolo              | 
  896452 |   318493 | C. D. Becker         | 
  896452 |   615968 | V. B. Duthon         | 
  896452 |   823663 | C. C. Charbonnier    | 
  896452 |   833091 | P. Hoffmeyer         | 
  896452 |   843054 | C. W. A. Pfirrmann   | 
  896452 |  1058596 | J. Menetrey          | 
  896452 |  2033639 | N. Magnenat-Thalmann |
```

From that I would like to create an entry for each of the authors for given paper with additional column 'Coauthors' - listing all coauthors delimited by space, like (but for each of the authors):

```
 paperid |   author          |                                                         coauthors                                                             
---------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  896452 | S. R. Duc         | C. C. Charbonnier C. D. Becker C. W. A. Pfirrmann F. Kolo J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann P. Hoffmeyer V. B. Duthon
  896452 | C. C. Charbonnier | S. R. Duc  C. D. Becker C. W. A. Pfirrmann F. Kolo J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann P. Hoffmeyer V. B. Duthon
... etc for each coauthor
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so for now I have a query which will create a cross product for each author from the column and the created coauthors column, but I still need to remove the single author from the coauthors column

```
SELECT foo.paperid, npa.name, foo.authors FROM newpaperauthor npa CROSS JOIN (select paperid, string_agg(name, ' ')  as authors                                
FROM newpaperauthor 
GROUP BY paperid 
ORDER BY paperid) foo ;
 paperid |         name         |                                                            authors                                                             
---------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  896452 | S. R. Duc            | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | F. Kolo              | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | C. D. Becker         | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | V. B. Duthon         | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | C. C. Charbonnier    | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | P. Hoffmeyer         | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | C. W. A. Pfirrmann   | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | J. Menetrey          | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | N. Magnenat-Thalmann | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
```

Comment: Check my recent answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24432345/131874

Comment: How do you know who the author is and who the coauthors are?

Comment: I want to create a result with as many rows as there were before the command of the solution. Take a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I got this finally  (at least for a table that has only one `paperid`) :

```
SELECT  foo.paperid, npa.name, foo.authors INTO npatest FROM newpaperauthor npa CROSS JOIN (select paperid, string_agg(name, ' ')  as authors 
FROM newpaperauthor 
GROUP BY paperid 
ORDER BY paperid) foo ; 
UPDATE npatest SET authors = regexp_replace(authors, concat(name, ' '), ''); 
SELECT * FROM npatest;

SELECT 9
UPDATE 9
 paperid |         name         |                                                            authors                                                             
---------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  896452 | S. R. Duc            | F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | F. Kolo              | S. R. Duc C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | C. D. Becker         | S. R. Duc F. Kolo V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | V. B. Duthon         | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | C. C. Charbonnier    | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | P. Hoffmeyer         | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | C. W. A. Pfirrmann   | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | J. Menetrey          | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann N. Magnenat-Thalmann
  896452 | N. Magnenat-Thalmann | S. R. Duc F. Kolo C. D. Becker V. B. Duthon C. C. Charbonnier P. Hoffmeyer C. W. A. Pfirrmann J. Menetrey N. Magnenat-Thalmann
```

I'll now try to find the solution for whole table (with many `paperid`s).

Answer (score 0):

I Assumed that main author is of minimum `authorid` within a `paperid` group.

```
SELECT PAPERID, 
       SPLIT_PART(STRING, ' ', 1) AS AUTHOR, 
       RIGHT( STRING, LENGTH(STRING) - LENGTH(SPLIT_PART(STRING, ' ', 1))-1 ) AS COAUTHORS
 FROM (
       SELECT PAPERID, 
              STRING_AGG(NAME, ' ' ORDER BY AUTHORID)  AS STRING
         FROM (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM PAPERWORK 
                WHERE PAPERID='896452'
              ) AS TEMP1
        GROUP BY PAPERID
      ) AS TEMP2;
```

Comment: I would like there to be as many rows as it were before running the command, having each of coauthors n the author column for that paper. Take a look at my updated question.

Comment: This solution splits the author's name with ' ' delimiter, so there is `S. R. Duc` as author it will be split into `S.` being the answer.